# Correctness of shaded-yellow

Tags: grammaticality

As shown in picture below, can I say state 13 is in shaded-yellow circle?

[image]

Comment: It would have to be *in **the** shaded yellow circle*, and I at least wouldn't hyphenate. It's an uncommon identification system though (probably because it doesn't work very well), so there's probably nothing standard about how to refer to it. A better alternative might be *the [cross-] **hatched** yellow circle*, which would at least have given me a better idea of what I was looking for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, except it's not ***cross**-hatched*, only hatched.

Comment: @StoneyB: My eyes and/or monitor aren't good enough for me to be certain. Anyway, all I meant was at least *hatch* would tell me to look for some lines. *Shaded* in this context didn't really convey anything to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The term *shaded-yellow* would mean that the yellow has been shaded, not the circle.
2. Circle 13 is not *shaded* (regardless of what your graphics program calls it!) but *hatched*. *Shaded* is used for a darker effect like a shadow (both 12 and 13 are in fact *shaded* in yellow) or, if you push it, a yellow of a different *shade*.
3. If you have to name its ornament, the *hatched yellow circle* is your best bet; BUT...
4. Since you've labeled the circle '13' which your question suggests is unique and your actual topic, why not refer to the circle simply by number?
5. `<rant>` I'm no graphics designer, but the designers in my shop would expel me if I allowed that hatching to go undeplored. It's entirely too busy and makes the number hard to read, especially on a lower-resolution monitor. Use a different color instead. That will not only look better, it will render this entire discussion of what to call it irrelevant. `</rant>`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what others have said: Circle #13 is *hatched*, and, even for Circle #12, I don't like *shaded-yellow* as an adjective.

For #12, you could call it *shaded*, you could call it *yellow*, but please don't call it *shaded-yellow*. If you really want a compound adjective, I would recommend *yellow-shaded* before *shaded-yellow.*

One other thought (this one is not absolute, but I think it's worth mentioning): I'd expect a [*shaded* circle](https://www.google.com/search?q=shaded%20circle&hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=yswtUcmOKuHa2wWg1ICADw&ved=0CC4QsAQ&biw=1186&bih=846) to have a grayish tint; when the shade color is a bright yellow, you could call it a *highlighted* circle instead.